# Android log cat showing android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.google.android.backup

Tags: android

i am a fresher to android and found the following exception in the log cat when i try to run my app in avd which shows the unfortunately my app cant run , please help

```
 android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.google.android.backup not found
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2172)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:2148)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:671)
        at com.google.android.gms.backup.an.<init>(SourceFile:47)
        at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportMigratorService.f(SourceFile:248)
        at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportMigratorService.b(SourceFile:196)
        at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportMigratorService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:131)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

my android manifest is as shown below

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
           <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cornex.criminalintent" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".CrimeListActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CrimePagerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a data backup application, you need to register your application with google backup service. This has been explained in the example. After registering , you have to specify its key in the AndroidManifest.XML

```
 <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:backupAgent="YOUR_BACKUP_AGENT">

   <meta-data 
      android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
      android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
</application>
```

Android provides `BackUpAgentHelper` class to handle all the operations of data backup. In order to use this class , you have to extend your class with it. Its syntax is given below:The corresponding backup agent can be implemented as demonstrated in the following listing.

```
import android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper;

public class YOUR_BACKUP_AGENT extends BackupAgentHelper {    

}
```

The persistent data that you want to backup is in either of the two forms. Either it could be SharedPrefrences or it could be File. Android supports both types of backup in the respective classes of SharedPreferencesBackupHelper and FileBackupHelper.

In order to use SharedPerefernceBackupHelper, you need to instantiate its object with the name of your sharedPerefernces File. Its syntax is given below −

```
static final String File_Name_Of_Prefrences = "myPrefrences";
SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, File_Name_Of_Prefrences);
```

The last thing you need to do is to call addHelper method by specifying the backup key string , and the helper object. Its syntax is given below −

```
addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
```

The addHelper method will automatically add a helper to a given data subset to the agent's configuration.

For more info See [this Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDataBackup/article.html) and [this article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_data_backup.htm)

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the `PackageManager` cannot found the package named `com.google.android.backup` installed on your device, emulator etc.

Install it then try to run the app again.

Please read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.NameNotFoundException.html).